# Dismal performance when using CoreOptions.bundle vs. CoreOptions.mavenBundle

Tags: pax-exam

I find that when I use org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.mavenBundle to deploy bundles from a maven repository, the deployment takes less than a minute, but when I deploy the same bundles using org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.bundle, specifying a file: url to the bundle on the local file system, the deployment takes over 8 minutes.  I expected CoreOptions.bundle to be faster since it's accessing local files.  Is there anything I can do to speed up the deployment when using CoreOptions.bundle?

Here are the versions I'm using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
  <artifactId>pax-exam-container-karaf</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
  <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
  <artifactId>pax-exam</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
  <artifactId>pax-url-aether</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the code I'm using to deploy the bundles from the file system:

```
// Inject our local bundle dependencies
URI deployBundlesDirUri = new File(deployBundlesDir).toURI();
for (String bundle : localBundles) {
    String name = deployBundlesDirUri.resolve(bundle).toString();
    options.add(bundle(name).start());
}
```

Here is the code I'm using when deploying the same bundles from a maven repo:

```
// Inject our maven dependencies
for (String[] dep : mavenDependencies) {
    options.add(mavenBundle()
           .groupId(dep[0])
           .artifactId(dep[1])
           .versionAsInProject().update(true).start()
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point in replacing `mvn:` URLs (equivalent to `mavenBundle()`) by `file:` URLs. Once the bundles are in the local repo, they will be provisioned from there.

Comment: Apart from that, if you can isolate the problem, please create a JIRA issue for Pax Exam and attach a self-contained test project.

Comment: To answer your question, we don't necessarily want to replace mvn: with file:, but we have some jars that we need to deploy to the test environment using file: because they are not in maven.  I only discovered this behavior while looking into why deploying the dependencies seemed to take a long time.  I initially thought that the problem might be with maven (e.g. perhaps the test env wasn't using the local maven repo) so I changed those to use file: instead to see if it made a difference.  I was surprised to find that deploy took MUCH longer.

I'll work on opening a JIRA issue with a test case